# How would i change a string in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript

I need some help as I can't figure out how to change a string in my chrome extension.

So here is some code.

```
var num = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("boxes")));
window.document.getElementById("boxes").innerHTML = "Looted Boxes: " + num;
```

And this throws me an error saying : "main.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Checklist:
Yes I have a p with the id boxes.
Yes I have liked my script correctly with it only running when DOM has fully loaded.

How would i solve this problem?

Comment: Checklist: no you don't. The error quite explicitly tells you that, so take a step back and verify your own claim: `const boxes = document.getElementById('boxes'); if (boxes) { boxes.textContent = `Looted boxes: ${num}`; } else { console.warn(`could not update box count: no #boxes element found`); }`

Comment: As this is a Chrome Extention I need to find a way to run this code inside of the extension and not on the webpage it is loaded on. And i do have a p with the id boxes

Comment: What do you mean "inside the extension"? Extensions execute in their own context, but with access to the page they're running on, and it very much looks like you're trying to access the page's DOM. Which is fine, you can do that no problem, but then your element selector would have worked - so you'll have to show some more code to prove your code is doing what your text claims it does. And you still want to put in that verifcation step because you might be surprised to see the code tell you that it could not get the element you're told it to get.

Comment: This is what I got so far. The script works fine until I add the innerHTML part. 
https://codepen.io/C4LLZ/pen/wvaMLMQ

Comment: Please update your post to be a self contained question. Links to external resources are prone to break and do not have future visitors of the site. Form a [mcve] and form your post around that. Web extensions don't need a lot of code to work, you should be able to fairly easily give the js code and manifest and explain when things work, and when they stop working. Remember, you're asking others to do your work for free, [make sure they have everything they need to know](/help/how-to-ask).